# google docs script document service edit text with format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am trying to edit text in google docs with google script. I am using following code

```
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
  .getBody();
var txt=body.getChild(i).asText()+" edited";
body.getChild(i).asText().editAsText().setText(txt);
```

But the problem is when i use "SetText" it resetting text format to original format. Suppose for following text

> Test document **content**

After executing the above script, it adding the text but bold formatting for "content" is gone and render as

> Test document content edited

Anyone has idea how to keep formatting?

Answer (score 0):

```
body.getChild(i).asText()
```

doesn't care what format your text is in, it just gets the string value.

Use [setBold(bold)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setBold(Boolean)) to set strings to bold.

Comment: i want to keep formatting of old text and append new text. I am not able to keep old text formatting when i do .asText()